# HTML markup in (FAQ) structured data

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

Is it allowed (and also consumed correctly by google) if I add HTML markup in my FAQ structured data? or should we strip out all HTML markup like

etc..?
How will content with markup be shown in the google search results?
example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML in the answer text is fine.

If you check [the official documentation from Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/faqpage), you will see that they actually use `p` and `b` tags themselves in some of the example code.

A common SEO trick is actually to include hyperlinks (a tag) in the answer. Google will display them in the search results!

Google will display the following HTML elements in the search results:

- `h1`
- `h2`
- `h3`
- `h4`
- `h5`
- `h6`
- `br`
- `ol`
- `ul`
- `li`
- `a`
- `p`
- `div`
- `b`
- `strong`

So basically (sub)headlines, lists, links, bolding, italics, and paragraphs.

All other HTML will simply be ignored: tags like `i` and `em`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!